# Multiple classes in one java application each with a main function

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have multiple classes in one java application, each one of them has a main function. I currently have to start each class manually. Is there any possible way to run them together in a specific order. So, when one class finishes the second one starts automatically. I thought of making one executable file but do not know from where to start and how to do this with multiple main functions.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to run the main fnctions from A, B and C. So write another class (say D) with

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    A.main(args);
    B.main(args);
    C.main(args);
}
```

Then run the D class.

Comment: I would use Java style array declarations or even varargs. ;)

Comment: Why, @PeterLawrey. Sometimes my brain reminds me on the good old times. There is a reason this is legal Java, after all! :)

Comment: BTW `public static int main()[] {` is also legal Java for legacy reasons. My first language was assembly and it influences my Java to this day ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a simple script (*.bat or *.sh) which runs your classes one after another:

```
java -cp myJar.jar  com.foo.mainClass1
java -cp myJar.jar  com.bar.mainClass2
java -cp myJar.jar  com.baz.mainClass3
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

The main methods are just methods called `main`.  If you want to call them in an order I would create a main method which calls each one in the order desired.

```
class ClassA {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ClassB.main(args);
        ClassC.main(args);
        ClassD.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the main function of other class from one class.
You can decide your sequence  like Class A calls Class B's Main .

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be this one :

```
interface App
{
     public void execMain(String args[]);
}

class MyApp1 implements App
{
  public void execMain(String args[])
  {
     // Stuff for  App1
  }
}

class MyApp2 implements App
{
  public void execMain(String args[])
  {
     // Stuff for  App2
  }
}

//...
```

And your Main finally :

```
public class Main
{
  // The list of apps
  private static App apps[] = new App[]
  {
     new MyApp1(),
     new MyApp2(),
     // ...
  }

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    for(App a : apps)
    {
      a.execMain(args);
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can add easily add other apps to be executed.